# How can I prevent paint from a mission tile decorative roof from creating streaks on my home's stucco siding?

Tags: paint

The front of my house has a small decorative Mission tile decorative roof. Three years ago, the tile was painted over and the house was re-stuccoed. There was a bit of running from the paint in the first two years after the work was done but last winter it started really running.

I don't know the kind of paint that was applied though I could possibly find out from the builders who did the work. I have found that it eventually does come off the white, unpainted stucco with oxygen bleach and light scrubbing.

Eventually I'd like to replace the tile but can't do that immediately. Is there something I can do to prevent the streaking? For example, is there a type of sealer or coating I could apply to the painted tile?

Comment: use oxygen bleach and light scrubbing on the tile

Comment: @jsotola Thanks, I didn't even consider removing the paint from the tile. What would you use to scrub? The tile likely dates from 1927 and does look brittle. I used a toothbrush on the stucco but the tile area is too big for that. Larger brush? Cloth?

Comment: i am no expert on roof tile ... i would not use cloth for any job where the cloth could catch a rough edge and break off a piece of the object that I am cleaning .... post another question about removing the paint ... new question is required because it is unrelated to this one ... please include closeup pictures of the roof tiles in the new question